# MYSQL PHP PDO Select Statement calling null

Tags: php, mysql, null

I'm trying to get the user's ID number from my table. For some reason the value always comes up "NULL", and it shouldn't be but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Here is how my table 'users' looks:

[image]

```
<?php
  ...........................................
  ....connection details (connection is not the problem as other SQL queries in my code work fine)
  ...........................................
  ...........................................

  $getvals = $db->prepare("SELECT MFG_LINE, PM_MECHANICAL, PM_DESIGN, PM_APPLICATIONS, PM_PROGRAM, DESCRIPTION FROM new_schedule WHERE ITEM = '$jobnum'");
    $getvals->execute();
    while ($row = $getvals->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $prod_line=$row["MFG_LINE"];
        $pe=$row["PM_MECHANICAL"];
        $de=$row["PM_DESIGN"];
        $ae=$row["PM_APPLICATIONS"];
        $ce=$row["PM_PROGRAM"];
        $model=$row["DESCRIPTION"];
    }



  /*Is job PE, DE, or CE?*/
    $engtype = rand(1,3);

    if ($engtype===1) { $engineer = $pe; }
    else if ($engtype===2) { $engineer = $de; }
    else if ($engtype===3) { $engineer = $ce; }
    else { $engineer = "Error 1005"; }

    echo $engineer;

    if ($engineer == null || $engineer = "") {
        $theengineer = 0;
        echo "nope";
    } else {        
        $getidnum = $db->prepare("SELECT USERID FROM users WHERE fullname LIKE '$engineer'");
        $getidnum->execute();
        $getthenum = $getidnum->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $theengineer = $getthenum['USERID'];
    }      

?>
```

The value is returning a NULL value when it should be returning "12". What am I missing here?

Comment: `var_dump($getthenum)` what do you get?

Comment: If you run `SELECT USERID FROM users WHERE fullname LIKE 'BRAD DAVIS'` from a MySQL client, whats the output?

Comment: hmm...when I do it that way it works. So I guess I need to update how I actually get my `$engineer` value

Comment: Yes indeed.  You should post the code that you actually used, not code that is mostly the same as your actual code, but modified a little bit before you post it.  That's like having a problem with your car which is making a funny noise, and taking it to the mechanic, but instead of bring the problem car, you bring one similar to the problem car.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, give this a try:

```
$getidnum = $db->prepare("SELECT USERID FROM users WHERE fullname LIKE :engineer");
$getidnum->execute(array(':engineer' => $engineer));
```

Comment: how do i retrieve the value from the array?

Comment: You define the value before the query, just as you're currently doing.

Comment: Then what are you not showing us? If the variable $engineer contains only "BRAD DAVIS" and nothing else, then there is nothing wrong with the query.

Comment: I added more code (see above). I'm pulling engineer names from another jobs table. Then choosing a random position ($de,$pe,$ce). The engineer will be the random chosen one. All names are in the user database. I echo the engineer's name to make sure it is pulling a name and it always does.

Comment: Ok...its stupid...but if you look at the "if" statement above the SQL call, I only had one "=" in there which was tripping it up yet not giving me the error.

Comment: @bagofmilk I am sure this is obvious, but just in case it isn't, as a good debug step, echo out the SQL statement in code.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the line that is 
`$getidnum = $db->prepare("SELECT USERID FROM users WHERE fullname LIKE '$engineer'");`. 
Change that to 
`$getidnum = $db->prepare("SELECT USERID FROM users WHERE fullname LIKE $engineer");`

Comment: I still get a null value.

Comment: Could you also echo the resulting SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe that there is spaces where not expected, so your query fails.

You need to add a wildcard front and end and the middle of the fullname.  So replace the space, or spaces (could be several, never trust user input), in the middle with "%".  So you have this:

$engineer = "%BRAD%DAVIS%";

Try that and let me know if it works?